# Rails find by first attribute or second attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following in my controller to find the device:

`Device.find_by_token(params[:token])`

Replacing  token with unique_id.

So the new query would be:

`Device.find_by_unique_id(params[:unique_id])`

For some of older requests, `unique_id` is not being passed in params and device won't be found.

How can I do something like:

`Device.find_by_token_or_unique_id(params[:token], params[:unique_id])`

or course this doesn't exist.

Also, I don't want to do:

```
if params[:token]
  Device.find_by_unique_id(params[:unique_id])
else
  Device.find_by_token(params[:token])
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you don't want to use if condition, may be you could use || operator. like `Device.find_by_unique_id(params[:unique_id]) || Device.find_by_token(params[:token])`

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, its not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Devise.where("token = ? OR unique_id = ?", params[:token], params[:unique_id]).first
```

Comment: If both params are passed, this is going to return all devices that matches that, it will somewhat work.

Comment: You said you are replacing `token` with `unique_id`, then how come there will be both params?

Comment: yeah you're right, sometimes unexpected things are passed, given that token and unique_id are both unique, its going to do the job. I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the previous answer could potentially return you 2 items, you could do this alternative:

```
user = Device.where(unique_id: params[:unique_id]).first
user ||= Device.where(token: params[:token]).first
```

Or you could implement Arel Helpers and be able to actual build it as a or query.
https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers

I prefer to using Arel as it makes your code no longer contain ANY SQL.

Comment: you're hitting the db twice potentially.

Comment: Correct you are in the case of the stepped queries.  However when using Arel you are able to build a proper 'OR' query that will not duplicate it.

The first example was just a means to make it work without a if block in the place, but the preferred way is through Arel.